# Data binding between a combobox and textbox

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a combobox and a separate texbox. I have set the datacontext of the combobox as a view model that specifies the history of entered text in the textbox. What I need is to have the selected value in combobox update to the text in the textbox instantaneously, after clicking in the specified item in the combobox. I have achieved this by binding the textbox text to the combobox selecteditem and setting the mode to twoway. 
But the issue I have run into is that when I write something in the textbox, and then click in the combobox, the first combobox item is replaced with the textbox text, when instead I want the (append) update in the combobox items to happen only after the user enters text in textbox and hits the return key.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to remove the binding of the ComboBox and TextBox. Then,

In Button Command Delegate add `SearchText` to the `ObservableCollection<string> HistoryItems`

```
HistoryItems.Add(SearchText);
```

Comment: Almost. Keep the binding of the TextBox to selected item of ComboBox **ONE WAY**. Then, add the Delegate suggested by @gaurawerma.

Comment: @Uri: Setting mode as oneway does not allow selected combobox item to populate the textbox automatically after clicking in the combobox. And history items are getting updated fine on hitting the return key, the workflow that's causing issue is: write in textbox, don't hit enter, click on combobox -> combobox selected item replaced by textbox text.

Comment: @user1157812 - it is important to set the oneway correctly. In this case: one way from the combobox to the textbox. This means that you put the embedding statement in the value of the textbox.